# Howto: Two tables should reference only one Item in a third table

Tags: postgresql

Maybe my question can be stupid, but I'm very new to postgresql, I'm
searching how apply a CONSTRAINT on my case for two tables can reference only one item in a third table, tables People & Vehicles should only reference to only one GPS, namely there should be only one GPS assigned for a vehicle OR for a person, how can I do that with Postgresql?
Thanks

```
Vehicles
+-----------------------------------------------+
|ID | Vehicle  | DIP  | Licence_Plate | GPS_FK  |
+-----------------------------------------------+

People
+------------------------------------------+
|ID | First_Name | Last_Name | DI | GPS_FK |
+------------------------------------------+

GPS
+-----------------------------------+
|ID | Serial | IMEI | Brand | Model |
+-----------------------------------+
```

Note: A GPS entity can only be referenced once.

Comment: Can multiple vehicles reference the same GPS?

Comment: Nope, that is another constraint.

Comment: Then you can switch the constraint. Make the table `GPS` reference `vehicles` and `people`. Make those columns nullable and add a check constraint that ensures that only one of them is not null.